# Reverse engineering check constraints & indexes w/ Hibernate?

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, reverse-engineering, jboss-tools, hibernate-tools

I've been tasked with reverse engineering Hibernate mappings from a large, legacy, sql server database.  The database makes extensive use of check constraints (several per table) and indexes, and while I would argue that these are DBA concerns, we're required to preserve them in the Hibernate mappings.

Using Hibernate Tools for Eclipse, I can successfully reverse engineer our tables into .hbm.xml files; however, none of the check constraints or indexes are present.  I know that it's possible to manually add both check constraints and indexes directly to the mapping, e.g.:

```
<class name="package.Tablename" 
       table="TABLENAME" 
       schema="dbo" 
       catalog="MyDB"
       check="START_DATE &lt; END_DATE"> <!-- here -->
   ...
   <property name="endDate" type="timestamp" index="IDX_END_DATE"> <!-- here -->
            <column name="END_DATE" />
   </property>
   ...
</class>
```

We have hundreds of tables and thousands of indexes/check constraints, so adding these by hand to the reverse engineered mappings isn't really feasible.

**Is it possible to get Hibernate Tools to spit these out for us?  If so, how?  If not, can anyone recommend another tool that will do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do this out of the box with Hibernate Tools; however, it is possible to add DDL to your mappings inside of [`<database-object>`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-database-object) elements.  In order to reverse engineer this information, you'll have to write a [custom utility class](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1009610) that is invoked via a [custom template](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.1.0.Beta1/hibernatetools/html_single/#hbmtemplate).

Since a boatload of `<database-object>`s didn't provide the level of abstraction and general user-friendlyness that my employer wanted, we opted not to take this approach and modeled our database in a different manner.